# Importing password-protected excel file into MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am currently trying to import tons of password-protected excel file into MS Access and create a report.

Is there any sample code I can use?

I've done some research, but I am kind of new to coding.

Greatly appreciated if anyone can help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow, please consider reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Bing: Access import password protected Excel. Review http://accessblog.net/2005/04/how-to-import-password-protected-excel.html